# Show equivalence (combinations)

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Show that for integers $1 \leq r < n$ we have

${n\choose r-1} = {n+2\choose r+1} - 2\times{n+1\choose r+1} + {n\choose r+1}$

I have expanded the RHS thusly, but I'm not sure where to go from here algebraically:

$\frac{(n+2)!}{(r+1)!(n-r+1)!} - \frac{2(n+1)!}{(r+1)!(n-r)!} + \frac{n!}{(r+1)!(n-r-1)!}$

Suggestions?

Comment: $\binom{n}{r+1}$ on both sides of the equality, making it wrong. (And I suggest not to use $*$ reserved for other things in math, such as convolutions. Use `\cdot` $\cdot$, `\times` $\times$, or just leave it blank.)

Comment: @metamorphy Sorry, It should have been $\binom{n}{r-1}$. I also changed the multiplication sign.

Comment: Now, a hint: use [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Formula) recurrence relation, several times, until you get only $\binom{n}{*}$ on the RHS.

Comment: Or you can view it as an easy implementation of the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

Comment: Think about this: you want to pick up $r+1$ out of $n+2$ items, among which 2 items are marked as special ones(Let's say they are $I_1,I_2$). Now you want to calculate how many schemes there are which contain both $I_1$ and $I_2$. LHS and RHS enumerate it in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{(n+2)!}{(r+1)!(n-r+1)!} - \frac{2(n+1)!}{(r+1)!(n-r)!} + \frac{n!}{(r+1)!(n-r-1)!}$

put them under a common denominator of $(r+1)!(n-r+1)!$

$=\frac{(n+2)!-2(n-r+1)(n+1)! + (n-r+1)(n-r)n!}{(r+1)!(n-r+1)!}$

$=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n!-2(n-r+1)(n+1)n! + (n-r+1)(n-r)n!}{(r+1)!(n-r+1)!}$

So factor the $n!$

$=\frac{n!((n+2)(n+1)-2(n-r+1)(n+1)+(n-r+1)(n-r))}{(r+1)!(n-r+1)!}$

$=\frac{n!(n^2+3n+2-2(n^2+n-rn-r+n+1)+n^2-2rn+r^2+n-r)}{(r+1)!(n-r+1)!}$

$=\frac{n!(r^2+r)}{(r+1)!(n-r+1)!}$

$=\frac{n!(r+1)r}{(r+1)!(n-r+1)!}$

$=\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r+1)!}$

$=$ $n \choose r-1$

But a better way to solve the problem would be to use the recurrence relation for binomial coefficients:

${n \choose k}={n-1 \choose k}+{n-1 \choose k-1}$

So we have

${n \choose k}-{n-1 \choose k}={n-1 \choose k-1}$

We can apply this to the rhs of your initial equation:

${n+2\choose r+1} - 2\times{n+1\choose r+1} + {n\choose r+1}$

$={n+2\choose r+1} - {n+1\choose r+1} -{n+1\choose r+1} + {n\choose r+1}$

applying our recurrence relation to the first two terms we get

$={n+1\choose r} -{n+1\choose r+1} + {n\choose r+1}$

$={n+1\choose r} -({n+1\choose r+1} - {n\choose r+1})$

applying the recurrence relation to the 2nd two terms we get:

$={n+1\choose r} -{n\choose r}$

applying the recurrence relation again we get:

$={n\choose r-1}$

Answer (score 1):

I ***highly*** recommend the beautiful combinatorial approaches given in the comments. However, just to finish out the algebraic approach you've started. First, judiciously expand the first few terms of the factorials $(n+2)!$ and $(r+1)!$ and "un-expand" some of the other factorials:

$\frac{(n+2)!}{(r+1)!(n-r+1)!} -2 \frac{(n+1)!}{(r+1)!(n-r)!} + \frac{n!}{(r+1)!(n-r-1)!}=$

$\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n!}{(r+1)(r)(r-1)!(n-r+1)!} - 2\frac{(n+1)n!(n-r+1)}{(r+1)(r)(r-1)!(n-r+1)!} + \frac{n!(n-r+1)(n-r-1)}{(r+1)(r)(r-1)!(n-r+1)!}=$

$\left(\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{(r+1)(r)} - 2\frac{(n+1)(n-r+1)}{(r+1)(r)} + \frac{(n-r+1)(n-r-1)}{(r+1)(r)}\right)\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r+1)!}= $

$\left(\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{(r+1)(r)} - 2\frac{(n+1)(n-r+1)}{(r+1)(r)} + \frac{(n-r+1)(n-r)}{(r+1)(r)}\right)\binom{n}{r-1}$

What's left to show then is that

$$\left(\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{(r+1)(r)} - 2\frac{(n+1)(n-r+1)}{(r+1)(r)} + \frac{(n-r+1)(n-r)}{(r+1)(r)}\right)=1.$$